# Can I implement QSPI (quad SPI) communication using an MCU that only supports ordinary SPI

Tags: spi, qspi

This question is *most probably* about pin-configurations registers.
I mean since QSPI is the same as SPI with more data bus-width (correct me if I'm wrong on this first assumption), then doesn't it mean that some pins can be configured to act as a QSPI peripheral?

It seems like a simple(?) DIY tweak to be able to implement QSPI communication by allocating/configuring a few more pins, and of course make/change things in the code, based on what a proper QSPI communication demands.

right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not, if it supports only spi then you could bit-bang quad-spi, but you won't have the speed of hardware controlled quad spi and dma. This could limit the bandwidth so if you need quad spi that is fast, then get a micro with hardware quad spi.

Comment: thanks. I didn't know I was actually asking a question about the ["bit-bang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging)  procedure.